# why android camera intent can't run for the second time

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

Me and my friend tried to write this intent camera apps to take a picture, save it into a folder, display it on imageView and create a hash value for the picture.
The problem here is it works fine for the first time of taking picture but when we tried to continue taking picture for the second time an error occur. Please help me see if there's any problem that we missed in the code.

Here are the codes

```
public class CameraApp extends Activity {

private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;

private ImageButton startBtn;
private ImageButton gallery;
private Uri imageUri;
private ImageView imageView;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date now = new Date();
String fileName = formatter.format(now);
final Context context = this;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_app);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    startBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    gallery = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startCamera();
        }
    });

    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"camera_app")),"image/*");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

public void startCamera() {
    File photo = null;
    File folder= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"camera_app");
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");


    if(folder.exists()){
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals( android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        photo = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "camera_app/DF_" + fileName + "_PIC.jpg");
    } 
    }

    else{
        folder.mkdirs();
        photo = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "camera_app/DF_" + fileName + "_PIC.jpg");
    }
    /*else {
        photo = new File(getCacheDir(), "camera_app/FILE_NAME.jpg");
    }    */

    if (photo != null) {

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }  
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //try {
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;

                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                //InputStream inputStream = cr.openInputStream(imageUri);

               Bitmap bitmap;
               try {
               InputStream inputStream = cr.openInputStream(imageUri);
               bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                java.security.MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

                  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                 int read;
                    do {
                      read = inputStream.read(buffer);
                      if (read > 0)
                        md.update(buffer, 0, read);
                    } while (read != -1);
                    inputStream.close();

                    byte[] digest = md.digest();

                    String hexString = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
                      hexString += Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) 
                                + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
                    }

               final EditText input = new EditText(this);

                input.setText("DF_" + fileName + "_PIC_");
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Rename")
                .setMessage("<MD5> "+ hexString)
                .setView(input) 

               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                        String value = input.getText().toString();
                        String value1 = value + ".jpg";
                        final File F=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "camera_app/DF_" + fileName + "_PIC.jpg");

                        File newfile=new File(F.getParent(),value1);
                        F.renameTo(newfile);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Do nothing.
                    }
                })
                .show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }


        } else {
            imageUri = null;
            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

        }       
    } 

}
```

}

xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="350dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton   
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/startBtn" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/img_button"/>

    <ImageButton

        android:id="@+id/gallery" 
        android:layout_width="430dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/gallery_icon"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

logcat-error

```
    08-27 05:58:02.505: E/vold(556): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
    08-27 05:58:02.505: E/vold(556): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (m)
    08-27 05:58:02.505: E/vold(556): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
    08-27 05:58:02.505: E/vold(556): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (m)
    08-27 05:58:02.626: E/flash_image(564): can't find recovery partition
    08-27 05:58:16.086: E/MemoryHeapBase(590): error opening /dev/pmem: No such file or directory
    08-27 05:58:16.086: E/SurfaceFlinger(590): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
    08-27 05:58:16.186: E/GLLogger(590): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot find library)
    08-27 05:58:16.276: E/GLLogger(590): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot find library)
    08-27 05:58:19.757: E/BatteryService(590): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/usb/online'
    08-27 05:58:19.757: E/BatteryService(590): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_vol'
    08-27 05:58:19.757: E/BatteryService(590): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_temp'
    08-27 05:58:20.355: E/EventHub(590): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
    08-27 05:58:20.526: E/EventHub(590): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
    08-27 05:58:20.885: E/System(590): Failure starting core service
    08-27 05:58:20.885: E/System(590): java.lang.SecurityException
    08-27 05:58:20.885: E/System(590):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    08-27 05:58:20.885: E/System(590):  at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
    08-27 05:58:20.885: E/System(590):  at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
    08-27 05:58:20.885: E/System(590):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
    08-27 05:58:20.895: E/AndroidRuntime(590): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
    08-27 05:58:22.086: E/LockPatternKeyguardView(590): Failed to bind to GLS while checking for account
    08-27 05:58:25.155: E/ApplicationContext(590): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/wallpaper-hints.xml
    08-27 05:58:25.890: E/ActivityThread(632): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
    08-27 05:58:26.681: E/ActivityThread(632): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
    08-27 05:58:26.782: E/ActivityThread(632): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
    08-27 05:58:34.680: E/MediaPlayer(561): Unable to to create media player
    08-27 05:58:34.680: E/CameraService(561): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
    08-27 05:58:34.710: E/MediaPlayer(561): Unable to to create media player
    08-27 05:58:34.720: E/CameraService(561): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
    08-27 05:58:36.660: E/Camera(738): _getParameters: picture-format=jpeg;picture-size=213x350;preview-format=yuv422sp;preview-frame-rate=15;preview-size=176x144
    08-27 05:58:36.660: E/Camera(738): setParameters()
    08-27 05:58:37.901: E/Camera(738): setParameters()
    08-27 05:58:46.891: E/MediaPlayer(561): Unable to to create media player
    08-27 05:58:46.891: E/CameraService(561): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
    08-27 05:58:46.891: E/MediaPlayer(561): Unable to to create media player
    08-27 05:58:46.891: E/CameraService(561): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
    08-27 05:58:47.821: E/Camera(738): _getParameters: picture-format=jpeg;picture-size=213x350;preview-format=yuv422sp;preview-frame-rate=15;preview-size=176x144
    08-27 05:58:47.840: E/Camera(738): setParameters()
    08-27 05:58:48.910: E/Camera(738): setParameters()
    08-27 05:59:10.970: E/MediaPlayer(561): Unable to to create media player
    08-27 05:59:10.970: E/CameraService(561): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
    08-27 05:59:11.000: E/MediaPlayer(561): Unable to to create media player
    08-27 05:59:11.000: E/CameraService(561): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
    08-27 05:59:11.990: E/Camera(738): _getParameters: picture-format=jpeg;picture-size=213x350;preview-format=yuv422sp;preview-frame-rate=15;preview-size=176x144
    08-27 05:59:11.990: E/Camera(738): setParameters()
    08-27 05:59:14.530: E/Camera(738): setParameters()
    : E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: Please describe the error you are seeing. It would be helpful to identify the problematic line. :)

Comment: would be nice if u could show us your logcat results.

Comment: the error i said only occur when we run it on the actual device. when we runit on the emulator it's fine.

Comment: This the error message we get from the device at second run "Unfortunately, CameraApplication has stopped." The logcat result is updated

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara it would be nice if u can help us =)

Comment: post the logcat right below FATAL EXCEPTION string

Comment: i don't see any fatal exception since it is working in the emulator. just that when it is used in my android device it has error the 2nd time

Comment: Is the problem that `getContextResolver()` is slow, and you are getting a force close on your app? It does sound that way. Use `adb logcat` to get the LogCat from the physical device and post that.